# IMAP fetch() returns command error: BAD [b' Command Argument Error. 12']

Tags: python-3.x, imap

I'm having trouble finding examples/troubleshooting tips online, and am not quite sure that I'm interpreting the documentation correctly.  Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

I'm connecting to an e-mail server, and want to read the e-mail subjects, and bodies.  I first make my connection like so:

```
import imaplib
c = imaplib.IMAP4_SSL(hostname, port)
c.login(username, password)

foldername = 'INBOX/SSR'
c.select(str.encode(foldername), readonly = True)

today = datetime.date.today().strftime('%d-%b-%Y')
searchcriteria = '(SENTON '{}')'.format(today)
typ, msg_ids = c.search(None, searchcriteria)
msg_ids = [s.decode('ascii') for s in msg_ids]
```

for idnumber in msg_ids:
print(c.fetch(idnumber, "(BODY.PEEK[HEADER])"))

The code and works and output looks as expected, up until the last line, at which point, I get

imaplib.error: FETCH command error: BAD [b' Command Argument Error. 12']

My line of thought, and subsequent testing examined the following possible issues:

1. bytes vs. string.  I converted input back to bytes, but the error remained constant
2. improper syntax: I tried other commands, such as BODY, SUBJECT, and ENVELOPE but still got the same message.

I'm not sure how to interpret the error, and don't really know where to start.  Referencing https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3501.html from pp. 102+, I noticed that the values are labeled differently, but don't understand what the issue is with my implementation.  How should I interpret the error?  What is wrong with my syntax?

P.S.  Correct me if I'm wrong, but the c.search shouldn't change my directory, yes?  As in, by selecting foldername, I "navigate" to the selected folder, but just searching only returns values and shouldn't change my location?

Comment: b BAD means that your command tagged 'b' contains a syntax error. Imaplib assigns that tag to something, so your next step is to increase the debug level on your imap object and see what exactly ahs been tagged 'b'.

Comment: How would I do so, increasing the debug level?

Comment: I don't remember. But I remember that when I needed it, I found it near the bottom of the main documentation page for imaplib. Search for 'debug'.

Comment: The trick here is to add the double quotes in the folder name. It will then be `foldername = '"INBOX/SSR"'`

Answer (score 6):

I encountered the same problem while I tried to list or select a new mailbox - `BAD [b' Command Argument Error. 12']`, in my case, it didn't work with “Sent Box”, but it worked well with “Outbox”, so the space symbol is the point.

So it worked with  `c.select('"{}"'.format("Sent Box")...`

Hope this information could help you.

Comment: In my case this worked fine also `c.select('"Bulk Mail"')` (but `c.select("'Bulk Mail'")` didn't)

Answer (score 0):

Your last line is not correct `msg_ids = [s.decode('ascii') for s in msg_ids]`

msg_ids is a list with bytes string, not with elements of a list - example: `[b'123 124 125']`

Change the last line into `msg_ids = msg_ids[0].split(b' ')` and it will work as expected.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar error. In the `foldername` part, for some reason, using the following worked for me:

```
foldername = '"Inbox/SSR"'
```