# IMAP login() returns command error: BAD [b' Command Argument Error. 12']

Tags: python, imaplib

I'm trying to access a shared mailbox within my company using Python, and am having a similar issue to what is outlined in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26981650/imap-fetch-returns-command-error-bad-b-command-argument-error-12), but my problem concerns the imaplib `login` command (rather than the imaplib `fetch` command).

My company has a policy of archiving emails into a separate mailbox after a period of time. This means that emails are moved to a (shared) archive mailbox , which has the prefix 'Online Archive - ' before the mailbox name. I am able to successfully log in when I run the following commands (having followed the steps outlined in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54070589/is-there-any-way-to-access-shared-mailbox-using-python-imaplib)):

```
import imaplib
imap_server = imaplib.IMAP4_SSL(host='outlook.office365.com', port=993, keyfile=None, certfile=None, ssl_context=None)
imap_server.login(myaddress@company.com+'\\\\{}'.format("sharedmailbox@company.com"),mypassword)
```

However, when I try to repeat the above for the archived mailbox of that above shared mailbox, I receive the following error: `error: LOGIN command error: BAD [b'Command Argument Error. 12']`

In other words, when I run the following,

```
import imaplib
imap_server = imaplib.IMAP4_SSL(host='outlook.office365.com', port=993, keyfile=None, certfile=None, ssl_context=None)
imap_server.login(myaddress@company.com+'\\\\{}'.format("Online Archive - sharedmailbox@company.com"),mypassword)
```

I receive the following error: `error: LOGIN command error: BAD [b'Command Argument Error. 12']`

From searching around and experimenting a bit (also using the second thread mentioned above), I'm pretty sure the issue is with the spaces in between the words that make up the name of this archived mailbox, and I've tried all sorts of combinations of quotation marks, periods, etc. to try and fix this, but no success.

Would you have any ideas?

Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: Have you fixed your problem in the meanwhile? I'm facing similar issues